# Could I use a 2-ch, 6-bit LVDS cable on an LCD that uses 1-ch, 6-bit LVDS?

Tags: lcd, lvds

I've bought a T.V53.03 control board to use with an old laptop display I have at my home. After searching for the display model I found it to be an LTN133AT09 display, which uses a 1-ch 6-bit LVDS cable. The problem I have is that the control board ships with a 2-ch 6-bit LVDS cable, and I was wondering if it will work out of the box with the display.

In summary, my two questions are:

- Will the LVDS cable work out of the box with my LCD?
- Can I cut out some wires of the LVDS 2-ch cable to make it compatible? Or should I buy a 1-ch cable?

Answer (score 1):

For high-speed links like LVDS it's a good idea to terminate unused pairs at both ends to minimize losses due to crosstalk. Apart from that only using 1...M pairs of a N-pair cable is fine.

Answer (score -1):

It's not about just cable, the board must be configured to send on signle link. If that is not possible then those two are just not compatible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I looked up the board spec sheet and it supports both 1Ch and 2Ch 6/8 bit. Considering this, could it work if I removed the even wires from the 2Ch LVDS cable?

Comment: You can leave them unconnected, but you have to check if the single channel is sent over odd or even pins. And otherwise check that each pin on the display is connected to correct pin on the control board. You must not simply expect the pinouts to match out of the box.